# How we should deal with seemingly easy questions

Tags: discussion, question-quality, answer-quality

This question comes from a question that was asked on SR, [What's a good education app?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19279/what-is-a-good-education-app) Although the question seems just fine to me, this strikes me as a question very likely to attract a lot of low quality answers. Such questions

- are very close from being too broad
- yet very interesting answers could be found

How should we deal with the risk of attracting numerous, bad answers on this kind of question?

Answer (score 2):

*My own answer to this question is based on [Alecos Papadopoulos' answer](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152/how-should-we-deal-with-what-are-the-causes-of-economic-phenomenon-x-questions) to a similar issue on Economics SE.*

Such questions:

a) Can very easily come out as "too broad", and for this matter should be edited as quick as possible if they're not very well stated out.

b) In reality are usually really complex yet interesting, since they are actually about daily choices faced by numerous users.

c) It would take a long discussion to reach one or more pertinent answers on such a topic, discussion which in my opinion makes sense and has it place on SR.

So I consider them as the hardest challenge to this website -to be able to formulate a condensed answer, providing some directions and tentative conclusions based on testing and on some relevant real-world info/experience, while keeping visible the alternatives their answer have to leave out.

I definitely want to see more of these questions here but without filtering low-quality answers they are for the moment big low-quality "I tried that too" magnets.